# How to toggle CSS class for Column element in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shiny-server

I have added **custom CSS class** using `class` attribute for a `column` element inside a `fluidRow` in `Shiny UI`. Now I need to **toggle CSS class** for this particular `column` from `Shiny Server`. I have given an `id` for this `column` and used -

```
toggleClass("column_id", "custom_class")
```

but, it is not working. I get an error like this -

```
Warning: Error in toggleClass: could not find function "toggleClass"
```

I have also tried with `addCssClass` and `addClass`. Both doesn't work though! How to solve this problem?

**Note**: I have checked the documentation of Shiny's `column` element. It doesn't seem to have `id` in it. Is there no way I can change the CSS class dynamically for this element?

Comment: These [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222469/shiny-change-background-color-of-htmloutput-conditionally/42260998#42260998) might be of help in case you are trying something similar.

Comment: may i assume you forgot to load the `shinyjs` library :)

Comment: @BigDataScientist: Thanks a ton! Problem solved after including `shinyjs` and using `useShinyjs()` in code.